# Loading CSV file to NumPy memmap array uses too much memory

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to load a 4.47GB CSV file to a memory-mapped NumPy array. On a GCP machine with 85GB of RAM, it takes approx. 500s to do so and results in a 1.03GB array.

The problem is that it consumes up to 26GB of RAM during the uploading-file-to-array process. Is there a way of modifying the following code so that it consumes less RAM (and, if possible, time) during the uploading process?

```
import tempfile, numpy as np

def create_memmap_ndarray_from_csv(csv_file): # load int8 csv file to int8 memory-mapped numpy array

    with open(csv_file, "r") as f:
        rows = len(f.readlines())
    with open(csv_file, "r") as f:
        cols = len(f.readline().split(','))

    memmap_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='ndarray', suffix='.memmap')
    arr_int8_mm = np.memmap(memmap_file, dtype=np.int8, mode='w+', shape=(rows,cols))

    arr_int8_mm = np.loadtxt(csv_file, dtype=np.int8, delimiter=',')
    return arr_int8_mm
```

Comment: After loading the csv using `loadtxt` use `np.save(filename, array)` which will store the file as binary `.npy` file. Then you can load the file using `np.load(filename, mmap_mode='r')` and you will have your memmap array with minimal memory consumption.

Comment: You don't seem to understand Python variable assignment.  With `A = fn()`, `fn()` is run first, creating what ever it needs to.  The result is assigned to `A` (and throwing away anything that was previously assigned to `A`).  In your code `arr_int8_mm` is the array created by `loadtxt`, not the memmap.

Comment: `loadtxt` reads the file line by line, collecting a list of lists (in effect your `readlines` and `split`).  Finally it makes an array from the result.  Conceivably your own reader could split a line at a time, and write the resulting array to a row of the `memmap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code in light of the comments to the original question. The updated code uses less memory: 8GB instead of 26GB. The `loadtext, readline, split` approach reduces the use of memory even further, but is just too slow.

```
import tempfile, numpy as np, pandas as pd

def create_ndarray_from_csv(csv_file): # load csv file to int8 normal/memmap ndarray

    df_int8 = pd.read_csv(csv_file, dtype=np.int8, header=None)
    arr_int8 = df_int8.values
    del df_int8

    memmap_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='ndarray-memmap', suffix='.npy')
    np.save(memmap_file.name, arr_int8)
    del arr_int8

    arr_mm_int8 = np.load(memmap_file.name, mmap_mode='r')
    return arr_mm_int8
```